# Java : Unknown error in exception handling

Tags: java, exception

i have a weird question. i had a quiz in my class today. One portion of the quiz was to find and correct errors in a short piece of code. one of the questions was like this

```
 class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("xyz");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("abc");
        }
    }
 }
```

I thought there was no error in the program but my professor insisted that there was. Can anyone guess what the error is?

Comment: just compiled and run and works for me; there is no compile /run error; maybe he expected public class Example or the fact that you shouldn't catch exceptions

Comment: Make no sense of using Try and Catch block just to print.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't `IOException` instead of just `Exception`?

Comment: @Mohammad Yes. i'm sure. So no exception?

Comment: @UsamaKhurshid read my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "error" may be that you don't need to handle any exception here: `System.out.println` does not specify any checked exception. It could simply be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
     System.out.println("xyz");        
}
```

Since the `Exception` class covers both checked and unchecked exceptions, then if you add a `catch` block here, in this case you would be handling only unchecked exceptions, which you should not normally handle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Error in the Above Program , but also there is no need to put a `try{} catch{}` ....since you *don't use any code that can throw an Exception* , for example a risky method like `Thread.sleep();`

So maybe that’s what your professor meant .

Answer (score 0):

Well, I see nothing that would keep this from compiling, but I do see some problems. To begin with, there are comments indicating the presence of code which is not there. Comments out of sync with code is always a problem. 
[EDIT: indentation errors have been edited away] And you're catching Exception e, which you really oughtn't to do. You should always catch a specific exception that you expect to encounter, and handle it specifically. Since there's no exception that System.out.println can throw, this would make the whole Exception handling block a problem.

Comment: the comments indicate statements. i'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

The following code snippet would throw a compilation error if used with `IOException`, since `System.out.println` would never throw an `IOException` but could throw `Exception` or `Throwable` which is its super class.

```
try {
    System.out.println("xyz");
} catch (IOException e) {
    //simple display error statement here
} finally {
    //simple print statement here
}
```

Comment: can you explain why this code will throw compilation error with 'IOException"?

Comment: `Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body` this is why. :) In other words,  `System.out.println` never throws and `IOException`.